# ArcGIS Experience Builder Sign-In Required after publishing

Tags: arcgis-online, authentication, arcgis-experience-builder

I'm trying to publish an Experience Builder page and share it publicly. Whenever I share the link, it requires people to "sign in" to an AGOL account to view it. Those who have an account/sign in are able to see it, however those who do not cannot view it. I thought if it was shared publicly that anyone with a link could see it.

Is there some sharing setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything must be shared publicly. This means the *Experience*, and the *Web Map* and the *Feature Service*.

Go back and find any and all contents inside the experience and share them as well.

Comment: I think that worked. Thank you!